# How do you program against a Database you can't see in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, visual-studio

I'm writings some ASP.NET and I tried connecting to my MySQL database. I found out GoDaddy doesn't support remote connecting to the database (free hosting).
Is there a way to program against it? Maybe prototyping the database locally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting up a local MySQL database to develop against would seem the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

A [mock data layer would work](http://aspalliance.com/1456_Beginning_to_Mock_with_Rhino_Mocks_and_MbUnit__Part_2.2) and give testing benefits as well.  [Rhino.Mocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I always use unbound controls so I've never run into that problem. That would be one option.

Another would be to have a "widget" class sit between your data and your program. During development, have the widget return what you expect. During testing and release, have the widget return real data.